# Remove File and Folder Permission of External Hard Drive

Tags: windows-7

I have done everything from other posts but still can't access some folders I just want pictures music and doc but Microsoft deems that I do not have permission to view my own files, I just want to use a drive from m old laptop as an external hard drive that anyone can read, I do not want any permissions at all.... ever.

Comment: Also: [How do I ensure other computers have access to files on an external (removable) hard drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/261737/how-do-i-ensure-other-computers-have-access-to-files-on-an-external-removable?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have "[no] permissions at all....ever". while using modern windows or linux file systems. If your volume is small you could use FAT which has no permissions implementation, but other than that, you have to understand permissions enough to configure them as you need them. It is not Microsoft's failing that you get that message.

For your issue Take Ownership of the entire drive as an Administrator. Then, on the root of the disk, grant the Everyone group Full Control on the folder.

Then Click the Advanced button, and then Change Permissions. Check the box that says "Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object". Then click Apply. The box will uncheck itself (its job is done), so you can just click OK. Now all authenticated users will have full control of the drive, as long as it remains attached to this windows PC. if you attach it to another computer, you will have to repeat these steps (permissions can never be portable).